# SideBar navigation collapse shows blank screen when bootstrap 4 css loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do side navigation bar with collapse. so that I have included `jquery 3.4.1` and CSS. But When `Bootstrap 4 css` and `Bootstrap js` added page turns into white screen. In console there will be no error. After removing bootstrap it is working fine.But bootstrap is essential. So that JS, CSS, JSP has been included for your reference. Please help me in this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hamburger").click(function(){
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("collapse");

});
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
body{
  background: #e1ecf2;
}
.wrapper{
  margin: 10px;
}
.wrapper .top_navbar{
  width:84%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper.collapse .top_navbar{
  width: 92.5%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .hamburger{
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #33AAAA;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  /* border-top-left-radius: 20px; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper . .hamburger div{
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #92a6e2;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#33AAAA,#80C477);
 /*  border-top-right-radius: 20px; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu .logo{
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul{
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a:hover{
  background: #4360b5;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a:hover i{
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  background:  linear-gradient(#80C477,#33AAAA);;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  /* border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; */
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-top: -60px
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #92a6e2;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a span.icon{
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a span.title{
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover,
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active{
  background: #4360b5;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover:before,
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active:before{
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .main_container{
  width: (100% - 200px);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
    
}

.wrapper .main_container .item{
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar{
  width: 70px;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a{
  text-align: center; 
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a span.icon{
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a span.title{
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.collapse .main_container{
  width: (100% - 70px);
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Responsive Side Navigation Bar</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">   
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Side.css">
<script src="../Scripts/fontawsome.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="wrapper">


  <div class="sidebar" >

   <ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="icon"><i
       class="fas fa-book"></i></span> <span class="title">Books</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="icon"><i
       class="fas fa-file-video"></i></span> <span class="title">Movies</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="icon"><i
       class="fas fa-volleyball-ball"></i></span> <span class="title">Sports</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active"> <span class="icon"><i
       class="fas fa-blog"></i></span> <span class="title">Blogs</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="icon"><i
       class="fas fa-leaf"></i></span> <span class="title">Nature</span>
    </a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="main_container">
   <div class="top_navbar" >
    <div class="hamburger" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="top_menu">
     <div class="logo">logo</div>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      </a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id ="Home">
    <jsp:include page="Home.jsp"/>
     </div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

problem comes if the below line added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I tried without bootstrap css it is working fine.But the bootstrap css is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Put your scripts in this order and don't forget to put important rules to your css which might be overriding some default bootstrap css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Side.css">
<script src="../Scripts/fontawsome.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Still facing the same issue

Comment: @vijaykumarg can you give the url for your website if it is on staging server or live ?

Comment: this is in my local system

Comment: @vijaykumarg Okay! I'll be trying to recreate the issue in my local and will post an answer if I find it